# Запуск watch через sh, как?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sh

Дано: 2 скрипта script.sh целью которых является генерация выводов от curl
Задача: запуск двух скриптов с заданной периодичностью (2с)
Решение: запуск происходит через watch

```
watch -n 2 "/root/script1.sh | tee -a 1.log" &>/dev/null &
watch -n 2 "/root/script2.sh | tee -a 2.log" &>/dev/null &
```

С этим все ок, но в какой то момент процесс watch падает и есть необходимость его перезапуска.
Сделал sh скрипт, для запуска его по крону:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! (pidof watch)
then
    watch -n 2 "/root/script1.sh | tee -a 1.log" &>/dev/null &
    watch -n 2 "/root/script2.sh | tee -a 2.log" &>/dev/null &
    echo "Watch restarted" | mail -s "CRON: Watch was restarted" user@domain.dom
fi
```

Если запускать руками, то все ок, если через крон (* * * * * root /root/watch-restart.sh), то watch не отрабатывается. Ошибок не заметил, письмо отправляется.
В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что-то все сложно у вас получается. Я бы сделал так: ```(while true; do /root/script1.sh; sleep 2; done) >> 1.log 2>/dev/null &``` И cron здесь не нужен

Comment: «В чем может быть проблема?» — абсолютно очевидно, что в этом: «в какой то момент процесс watch падает».

Comment: Если использовать цикл, то изменил бы немного команду запуска, что бы избежать множественного запуска одного скрипта: *while true; do* `flock -w0 /var/run/script1.lock /root/script1.sh`; sleep 2; done и действительно, не нужно будет использовать watch и дополнительного задания в кроне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По порядку, ответ в явном виде не будет подходить для данного набора команд, но в целом подойдет для выполнения поставленной задачи.

Указать содержимое скрипта script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    flock -w0 /var/run/script1.lock /root/script1.sh >> 1.log & 
    flock -w0 /var/run/script2.lock /root/script2.sh >> 2.log &
    sleep 2
done
```

в данном случае будет использоваться бесконечный цикл `while true` внутри которого будет указан запуск скриптов по порядку с отвязкой от сессии, исключая ожидания выполнения скрипта. Так же установлена защита от множественного запуска скрипта, если к примеру по истечению 2 секунд предыдущая итерация скрипта не завершила работу, `flock` не создаст новый процесс.
Выход из цикла не предусмотрен, в связи с чем в задании для крона нет необходимости (упоминалось в комментариях), либо добавить строку вида `@reboot root /root/script.sh` что бы после перезагрузки системы, скрипт автоматически стартовал.

В версии вашего скрипта используется конструкция записи лог файла вида `tee -a 2.log" &>/dev/null`, которую можно заменить на `>>` перенаправление вывода в файл, + дополнительно если нужно логировать stderr то после названия лога дописать `2>&1` через пробел `>> 1.log 2>&1 &`

По поводу проблемы запуска watch через крон, вероятнее всего отсутствует переменноe окружение PATH, для разбора причины добавьте перенаправление вывода в задании, по примеру:

```
* * * * * root /root/watch-restart.sh > /tmp/watch-restart.tmp 2>&1
```